# VueJS: how to write path with parameter correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I'm following [a tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wv4kyqUqqJQ&list=PLpOqH6AE0tNh7-Z-Lka9e0hRA2OdNB0dx&index=13) and the paths with parameter are not working.

```
data() {
    return {
        id: this.$route.params.id,
        element: {
            title: '',
            description: '',
        }
    }
},
methods: {
        getBook() {
            const path = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/${this.id}/'
            axios.get(path).then((response) => {
                this.element.title = response.data.title
                this.element.description = response.data.description
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })          
    },
    created() {
        this.getBook()
    }
```

**In console:**

```
"GET /api/v1/books/$%7Bthis.id%7D/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2410
```

What exactly is wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: Use `\`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/${this.id}`\` (backticks), not '' (single quotes). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backticks ``` `` ```:

```
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/${this.id}/`
```

or just:

```
'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books/'+this.id
```